# how can i exclude a member with a certain role from a map? [discord.js]

Tags: discord.js

I need a command that gives me a list of members with `Xrole` but without `Yrole`. If `member1` has `Xrole`, include it in the list; if `member2` has `Xrole` *and* `Yrole`, exclude from the list.

My current code:

```js
const Xrole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('id');
message.guild.roles.cache
 .get(Xrole.id)
 .members.map((m) => m.user.tag)
 .join('\n');
```

This works fine, but I don't know how to exclude members with an extra role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) on the collection of [`GuildMemberManage.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache)

```js
message.guild.members.cache
 .filter(
  (member) =>
   member.roles.cache.has('X Role ID') && !member.roles.cache.has('Y Role ID')
 )
 .map((m) => m.user.tag)
 .join('\n');
```